# NSFetchRequest for all children of a parent

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

How do I fetch all child entities of a parent?

I have a table populated by a parent entity in Core Data. When the user touches a cell I intend to show another table with all children of that parent.

How does the `NSFetchRequest` look like for this please?

**Edit:**

model is like this:

> student>>dates [one to many, one student have many days]

So I want all dates for any given student (selected by touching in student table cell for that student), then populate dates table with dates for that student.

Thanks!

Comment: Without the model is difficult to understand the problem. Share some details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your first table delegate, when you touch a specific cell, I'll inject the specific parent property to the second table controller. For example:

```
SecondController secondController = ... // alloc-init
secondController.studentToGrab = ...
```

where `SecondController` declaration has a `studentToGrab` property like the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Student* studentToGrab; // use strong with ARC, if non-ARC remember to release it
```

and in definition synthesize it.

Then in your second controller, within `viewDidLoad` method you could do:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"YourNameEntityForDate" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"student == %@", studentToGrab];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

// you can also use a sortdescriptors to order dates...

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *resultArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (error != nil) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    abort();
}

// use resultArray to populate something...
```

**A remark** when you deal with table you could also use `NSFetchedResultController` class. It has advantages when used for displaying data in tables.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the entity and the class names are `Student` and `Date`, and the reverse relationship for `Date`->`Student` is called `student`,

```
Student *aStudent = ...;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity: [NSEntityDescription entityForName: @"Date" inManagedObjectContext: [aStudent managedObjectContext]]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"student == %@", aStudent]];
```

Comment: nice post. The key is the reverse relationship. If there was no reverse relationship, it would more difficult to use fetch request.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a separate fetch request for this. All of the objects from the to-many relationship (don't call them child entities, that is misleading and incorrect) are available by accessing the relationship from the student object - something like `student.dates`. This gives you an NSSet, you can sort it and turn it to an array if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

If you have custom classes, you could traverse the generated relationship (`return [student dates]`). That will get you an unordered NSSet on iOS4, or, you can do it with a fetch request (note I use ARC so no releases/autoreleases here):

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Date"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:moc];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSMutableArray *predicates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3];
[predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"student == %@", aStudent]];

// You might add other predicates
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates]];

// and if you want sorted results (why not, get the database to do it for you)
// sort by date to the top
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateAdded" ascending:NO]];
}
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *sorted = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (error) {
    // Handle the error, do something useful
}

return sorted;
```